# Why I cannot download pdf files?

Tags: debian, browser, download, plugin

I use Debian (Linux) and since some day I cannot download any `.pdf` file. I don't know if it's because of the web browser (I'm using Epiphany and the other ones do not work).

I don't know how to use the terminal properly, so any simple answer would be welcome.

Comment: What happens when you try to open a PDF? E.g. when you click [this link](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~golin/Talks/Knuth_Yao_SODA05.pdf) ? Try to explain more then *"Cannot download"*

Comment: @Sukminder The computer is from the university that I study. I just use it to print some lecture notes. The PDF reader installed is the Document Viewer. The message that appears after downloading some file is written in other language (not english) but I will try to translate it properly: "Cannot open the file. The viewer does not support plain text files.".

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. If it is a bad download sometimes the server can send a plain text file with message. Else it could be bad extension – such as it actually is a plain text file. Did you try the link in my previous comment?

Comment: @Sukminder I tried the link and I've got the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to open the file in a text-editor? (Not PDF-viewer)

Comment: @Sukminder I cannot open it with any text-editor. I always got a message  "Error in the input/output".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a PDF reader installed? Adobe Reader has a [Debian package](http://get.adobe.com/reader/completion/?installer=Reader_9.5.4_English_for_Linux_%28.deb%29) you can use.

Comment: The PDF reader installed is the Document Viewer. The message that appears after downloading some file is written in other language (not english) but I will try to translate it properly: "Cannot open the file. The viewer does not support plain text files.".